# Broken my pop-OS while upgrading

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, crash, interrupt

I mistakenly broke my pop-OS and when I restart it then I get an error window with

> ```
> **Error occured which system cannot restored. Contact administrator**
> ```

I already tried `apt-get dist-upgrade` in recovery but it shows error shown in [image: picture].

I tried several suggestions but am not able to upgrade it because of this error.

Basically I mistakenly pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> during upgrading which I wasn't supposed to do.

Please help because I lost all my data otherwise.

Comment: First of all: Remain calm. Your system is not booting right now, but unless you have some encryption going the data is unaffected and still there. Recovering from an interrupted upgrade is cumbersome but not impossible. Have you tried `apt-get install --fix-missing`?

Comment: @Hermann yes i tried it but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue as I got an error that the following packages have unmet dependencies which we can see in the above picture so I simply download those dependencies by entering command `sudo apt install libavfilter7:i386` and I was able to get rid of that problem.